# Every positive integer can be expressed uniquely as $N = a_0 + a_1 2 + a_n 2^n $ and all $ a_i $ belongs to $\{0, 1\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying assignment problems of an Institute in which I don't study. I am unable to think about this problem.

> Problem ->Prove that every positive integer can be expressed uniquely as $N = a_0 + a_1 2 + a_n 2^n $ and all $ a_i $ belongs to $\{0, 1\}$.

Can someone please help.

Comment: As stated, the claim is false for $N=14$

Comment: I think he meant $N=\sum_{i=0}^na_i2^i$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $N=a_0+a_12+\cdots+a_i2^i+\cdots+a_n2^n$?

Comment: @W.Tanner yes!!

Comment: @XWLPDK So the question is just asking you to prove that every positive integer has a unique binary representation. This is easily proved by induction - assume it is is true for $0 \le N \lt 2^n$ and then show it must also be true for $2^n \le N \lt 2^{n+1}$.

Answer (score -2):

The statement is false. For example, the number $N=12$ cannot be written as $12=a_0 + 2a_1 + 2^n a_n$ where $a_i\in\{0,1\}$, and it is easy to show this since:

- $a_n$ must be $1$, since otherwise, $a_0 + 2a_1 + 2^n a_n=a_0+2a_1 < 3 < 12$.
- $n$ must be equal to $3$, since $n\leq 2$ means that $a_0 + 2a_1 + 2^n a_n$ is at most $7$, and $n\geq 4$, then $a_0 + 2a_1 + 2^n a_n$ is at least $16$.
- $12=a_0 + 2a_1 + 2^n a_n$ means that $a_0=0$, since the left side is even, and if $a_0=1$, then the right side is odd.
- Therefore, $12=2a_1 + 2^3 a_3 = 2a_1 + 8a_3$, meaning $6=a_1+4a_3$, which is impossible (either $a_1=0$, in which case $6=4a_3$, which is impossible since $a_3$ must be $0$ or $1$, or $a_1=1$, in which case $a_1+4a_3$ is odd, while $6$ is even).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question you answered is not what OP meant to ask (see comments to OP above)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I know. But I answered it as it was asked, as an educational moment to the OP.